# sed regexp address case-insensitive matching

Tags: linux, ubuntu, debian, regex, sed

How to specify a `sed` regexp address which is case-insensitive?

E.g.,

`sed '/my-kw/d'`

But I want `sed` to remove lines with `my-kw` in any cases.

Thanks

Comment: Should this question be migrated to the Unix and Linux StackExchange community?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
sed '/my-kw/Id'
```

This will perform the match case-insensitive.

The switch is in uppercase itself, to avoid confusion with the `i` command that is offered by `sed` to insert a line into the stream.

Comment: Perfect thanks. Hmm, hope my following multi-line comment can go through

    $ jot -c 5 'A' | tee /dev/tty | sed '/c/Id'
    A
    B
    C
    D
    E
    A
    B
    D
    E

Comment: No, my prevous multi-line comment didn't go through with nice formatting, but you can see that `C` was removed from the list. You can run the sample your self `jot -c 5 'A' | tee /dev/tty | sed '/c/Id'`, where the jot is from the athena-jot package under Debian/Ubuntu.

Comment: Note that **I** is a GNU sed extension.

Comment: This is not portable. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4412945/case-insensitive-search-replace-with-sed#comment31685516_4412964

Answer (score 5):

Just use the `I` switch:

```
$ echo fooFOO | sed 's/o/a/Id'
faaFaa
```

From the [`sed` FAQ](http://sed.sourceforge.net/sedfaq3.html):

> GNU sed 3.02 and ssed also offer the /I switch for doing a case-insensitive match. For example,
>
> ```
> echo ONE TWO | sed "s/one/unos/I"      # prints "unos TWO"
> ```

Comment: and the ones who upvote the answer, my question is for sed **address**. See my comment on other thread.

Comment: I am working with `n` - quiet and `p` - print flag to print part of a line: `$(dhclient $eth|sed -nr 's/rtnetlink answers: (.*)/\1/Ip')`. But the caseinsensitive does not work. Actual behaviour `RTNETLINK answers: Operation not permitted`, expected `Operation not permitted`. Same `$(dhclient $eth|sed -r 's/rtnetlink answers: (.*)/\1/I')`

Comment: @Timo please ask a new question where you can show _exact_ input and desired output and tell us what version/implementation of sed you have. The match is working, otherwise you would have no output, so it will be something about your input.

Comment: You are right, nothing to do with case problem, but with input. I [posted a new one](https://superuser.com/questions/1678216/pipe-output-of-dhclient-with-sed)

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you:

sed '/[mM][yY]-[kK][wW]/d' file
or:

sed 'h;y/abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz/ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ/;/MY-KW/d;x' file