# Pipe Output of dhclient with sed

Tags: debian, zsh, sed, pipe, gnu

### Goal

Limit output of `dhclient`.

#### Code

`dhclient eth0|sed 's/answers//'`

#### expected behaviour

`RTNETLINK : Operation not permitted`

#### got

`RTNETLINK answers: Operation not permitted`

#### Piping ifconfig works

`ifconfig eth| sed 's/eth//'` -> `[cut the search]:flags=41...`

#### Env

`sed (GNU sed) 4.7 Packaged by Debian`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Community Terdon answered my question, obviously he knows what my hurt is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `dhclient` command needs to be run as root. When running it as a regular user, you get an error message

```
$ dhclient enp1s0:
RTNETLINK answers: Operation not permitted
```

Error messages are normally printed to standard error (stderr) while the pipe (`|`) will redirect only standard output (`stdout`). This is why your sed command isn't working: it doesn't actually get any input at all, what you are seeing is the standard error of the first command.

To redirect and parse standard error, you can use `2>&1` (redirect output stream 2, standard error, to output stream 1, standard output):

```
$ dhclient enp1s0 2>&1 | sed 's/answers//'
RTNETLINK : Operation not permitted
```

For more details on these two streams and the ways of redirecting each of them, see https://askubuntu.com/a/625230/85695.

Comment: I want to get back an errorcode with `$?` in case I am not `root`, but I get `0` back. How is that?

Comment: @Timo the command runs, which is why you get `1`, but then it tries to check things and fails. It looks like the developers of `dhclient` wrote it that way. I'm afraid there's nothing to do.